# How do I fix this error? Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'?

Tags: java, command-line

When running a .java file in the command line on Windows 8, got this error:

`Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`

I know that there are already questions concerning similar errors, but I don't understand why it's asking for a **lower** version.  How can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly has produced that error? Running Java from the command line?

Comment: Yeah, I was using the command line

Comment: @Josh Using the command line **to do what**?

Comment: I ran my code using the `java` command.